# Copy file from buffer "a" in vim to new txt file

Tags: vim, copy

Would someone help me please with command for copy data from buffer "a" into new .txt file? I have copied 30 lines from Vi through command (`"a30yy`) into buffer "a" and I do not known how to copy this data into new .txt file.

Comment: what do you mean by **buffer "a"**?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Looks like your question is about `VIM` (you're asking about a buffer "a"). If that's the case, is offtopic here, you should ask on [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have copied 30 lines from Vi through command (a30yy) into buffer "a" and I do not known how to copy those data into new txt file.

Comment: @MrShunz It's perfectly on-topic for AskUbuntu as well. `vim` is one of the default tools on Ubuntu. Although admittedly with a dedicated site to `vim` there's greater chance for questions to be answered, they're still very much welcome here

Comment: I dont known if there isnt mistake in question. I have to complete this task: Open help for command date, copy first 30 lines and safe them to new txt file. For now I have this: man date; a30yy; touch date.txt; and I do not known what next :-(

Comment: @LukkeeF `man` uses `less`, not `vim` to show content.  You probably want this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172628/85039  If you still want to open manpage in `vim` you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740302/3701431

Comment: And how to save only first 30 lines? When I use command s date.txt; that save whole content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have copied the lines (`"a30yy`), open the new file (`:e some-file` - open in current split/window, `:tabe some-file` - open in new tab, `:vs some-file` - open in new vertical split/window, etc.), navigate to the position where you want to paste it, and do `"ap` (or `"aP` if you want to paste before the cursor).

---

Technically, `a` here is [a register](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#registers), not [a buffer](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#buffers). Registers are where text that's copied (yanked) or cut (deleted) get stored. Buffers in Vim are the entities which represent files. So when you open a file in Vim, a new buffer is created, which represents that file. The buffer is displayed in a [window](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#windows-intro) (aka split), and [tabs](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#tab-page-intro) contain arrangements of windows. The same buffer can be displayed in multiple windows. See [this Vi & Vim post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9017/205).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save certain sequential lines from file a into new file b, then you can [use visual selection to write into new file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799933/3701431).

```
:'<,'>w new.txt
```

But if your goal is to [dump register contents to file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12006/7589) as suggested by muru on the linked post, use  this:

```
:call writefile(getreg('a', 1, 1), "new_filename.txt")
```

If you want to make it shorter, you can define your own function in `~/.vimrc` (call it `Wrf` for write-register-to-file)

```
function Wrf(regname,fname)
    call writefile(getreg(a:regname,1,1),a:fname)
endfunction
```

Now you can just do in vim:

```
:call Wrf('a','new_textfile.txt')
```